# Inheritance Exercise

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following question to solve as an exercise from a Java course.

> Consider the following classes.
>
> ```
> public class Water extends Earth {
>     public void method1() {
>         System.out.println("Water 1");
>     }
>
>     public void method3() {
>         System.out.println("Water 3");
>     }
> }
>
> public class Fire {
>     public void method1() {
>         System.out.println("Fire 1");
>     }
>
>     public void method2() {
>         System.out.println("Fire 2");
>         method1();
>     }
> }
>
> public class Earth extends Fire {
>     public void method1() {
>         System.out.println("Earth 1");
>         super.method1();
>     }
> }
>
> public class Air extends Fire {
>     public void method3() {
>         System.out.println("Air 3");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Assume the following variables have been defined.
>
> ```
> Fire var1 = new Water();
> Fire var2 = new Earth();
> Fire var3 = new Fire();
> Object var4 = new Earth();
> Earth var5 = new Water();
> Fire var6 = new Air();
> ```
>
> For each of the following questions, give the output,
> or write "compiler error" or "runtime error".

and I am suppose to write the result when the following is called,

```
((Earth) var1).method2();
```

which I thought to be a compiler error as the the CastToType `Earth` does not have a `method2()`. However, the answer is `Fire 2 / Water 1`. Could someone explain to me why this doesn't give a `compiler error` but instead goes to `public class Fire`'s `method2()`?

Comment: `Earth` *does* have a `method2` method. It inherited it from `Fire`.

Comment: "`Earth` does not have a `method2()`" It actually does. `Earth` inherits from `Fire` and `Fire` has a `method2`.

Comment: Not related to the question, but this class hierarchy makes no sense. I find it a very bad idea to teach inheritance with examples such as "Air extends Fire" or "Water extends Earth".